# Org-mode: Adding Attributes and Captions to Babel Table Results

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Given the following org-mode file:

```
#+TITLE: Tests

#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[outputdir=build]{minted}

* Export Configuration

#+name: Configuration
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results silent :exports both
  (org-babel-do-load-languages
   'org-babel-load-languages
   '((emacs-lisp . t)
     (shell . t)
     (python . t)
     (org . t)
     (latex . t)))
#+end_src

#+NAME: attr_wrap
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :var data="" tex="1.0\\textwidth" html="50%" caption="" :results output
  echo "#+ATTR_LATEX: :width $tex"
  echo "#+ATTR_HTML: :style $html"
  if [ -n "$caption" ]; then echo "#+CAPTION: $caption" ; fi
  echo "$data"
#+END_SRC

#+name: read-csv
#+begin_src python :results value table silent :var csvfile="" header="" :exports none :eval yes :colnames yes :rownames yes
  import csv
  with open(csvfile, 'r') as f:
       data = [row for row in csv.reader(f)]
       if header and len(data) >= 2:
          # Inserts an empty line to create a hline.
          data.insert(1, None)
       return data
#+end_src

* Tests

#+CALL: read-csv("build/test.csv", "yes") :post attr_wrap(data=*this*, tex="0.4\\textwidth", html="width:50%", caption="Result figure\\nbsp{}[[fig:link]")
```

My intent behind this is:

During org-mode export, import a dynamically generated CSV file as an org-mode
table, possibly operating slightly on it and then adding captions and
latex-width / html-styling to it.

According to the post-processing section in
https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html, it seems like something
like this should be possible, but I cannot get it to work. The `:post` header
argument only inserts the read Python "table" in-verbatim. Is there some way of
converting these arguments before passing them into the post-processing
function?

Additionally, is there some way of actually importing CSV files directly with
Elisp or org? I figured the `org-table-import` would do this, but that only
inserts into the org-mode buffer rather than creates a table.

Lastly, is there some way of breaking up the really long `#+CALL:` lines? Even
in this small example, the line quickly gets too long for comfort.